# Are there any anonymous OpenID providers similar to Gawker's "burner"?

Tags: authentication, privacy, anonymity, openid, sso

Gwaker has an [anonymous commenting system called Burner](http://econsultancy.com/us/blog/9710-gawker-sides-with-a-different-vision-of-internet-publishing).  It is offered as an alternative to Facebook, Twitter and Google.

- What's the difference between Burner and creating a throwaway Google , Facebook, or Twitter account?
- Is the difference between Gawker's "Burner" and the other providers mainly the Terms of Service?
- Is there an OpenID site that offers similar protections?  (e.g. the Duck Duck Go of OpenID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is probably equivalent to a throwaway account, although with less work involved. Another similar service that creates a disposable openid is at http://openid.anonymity.com/

Other services like myopenid.com allow you to create multiple aliases for a single account. Liquidid.net allows you to create multiple anonymous email aliases.

I guess it all depends what you want to accomplish and how permanent you want to make the identity.

Comment: "we have made the decision to end of life the myOpenID service. myOpenID will be turned off on February 1, 2014."  there are other alternatives you could list, though